# How to quickly tell if two matrices are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My professor gave us a list of a bunch of 2x2 matrices and asked if they were similar to the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Is there a quick way to do this? I literally need so much help.

Comment: Determinant and trace must coincide.

Comment: Check trace and determinant first. If two matrices are similar then both the trace and the determinant must coincide. Be warned that this is not a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: In this particular case though, this is necessary and sufficient. If the determinant and trace match this matrix, the characteristic polynomial is $x^2 - 1$, and there are distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: yes, since there can only be two eigenvalues and the determinant and trace give two equations it will be unique for 2x2 matrices

Comment: @mathreadler Importantly, this only works because the matrix given has distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: @B.Mehta it would be a trivial case of Jordan blocks to investigate.